# High volume insert/update for data size of 20 KB on an average

Tags: database-design, big-data

Needed to insert/update 80 million records as fast as possible. However, while write is happening I don't want my active read query to be blocked, the rate of which is around 5k reads per second.

what will be the best database to handle this? my application is hosted on AWS, and the data come in JSON format in Kafka and the size per data varies from 20 to 30 KB

Comment: [Edit] the question and explain what you are going to _do_ with the data. Modify it? Query it? Archive it? Where are you planning to run the database? On-prem hardware? VM? Cloud? SaaS?

Comment: @vonPryz we are going to query the DB and my application is hosted on AWS.